# Do I need to manually create Strapi relations after POSTing to create a new database entry?

Tags: strapi

I have two content types

Auction
Bid

An Auction has many Bids.
A Bid has one Auction.

I POST to `/bids` to create a new Bid. In the body I have `auction: auctionId` to link that Bid to the correct Auction. That works as expected. The Auction shows up properly in the Bid relation field.

However, the Bid doesn’t show up in the Bid relation field for the Auction.

Do I need to manually create the Auction to Bid relation with a PUT to /auctions/:auctionId??

Answer (score 0):

No you have selected the wrong relation. change it to "belongs to many" instead of "has many" relation.